# Reduced PCA summary

Tags: r, pca

I have a dataset with 561 variables and 10299 observations. All variables are numeric

Im trying to do PCA. Im removing first feature which is the dependent variable (its categorical)

```
df1.pca = prcomp (df1[,-1])
```

df1.pca yields a large component with the same number of PC's than the initial dataset has in variables.

Im trying to vizualize the PCA summary but when running summary (my.pca) will yield a lot of information.

```
summary(df1.pca)
Importance of components:
                          PC1     PC2     PC3     PC4     PC5     PC6     PC7     PC8     PC9    PC10    PC11    PC12    PC13    PC14    PC15    PC16    PC17
Standard deviation     5.8092 1.60880 1.47618 0.99435 0.93471 0.80732 0.80232 0.76397 0.72182 0.69361 0.67622 0.60624 0.59093 0.55886 0.53204 0.52563 0.50579
                          PC18    PC19    PC20   PC21    PC22    PC23    PC24    PC25    PC26    PC27    PC28    PC29    PC30   PC31    PC32    PC33    PC34
Standard deviation     0.49256 0.48493 0.47324 0.4714 0.45907 0.44536 0.43740 0.43329 0.42408 0.41055 0.40422 0.40050 0.39252 0.3898 0.38444 0.37860 0.36667
```

I would like to see only the sd and proportion for the first X principal components. Is it possible? I would expect something like this if my code asks for the first 6 PC:

```
summary(df1.pca)
## Importance of components:
##                          PC1     PC2     PC3     PC4     PC5     PC6
## Standard deviation     3.360 0.69114 0.40463 0.19246 0.11371 0.10043
## Proportion of Variance 0.941 0.03981 0.01364 0.00309 0.00108 0.00084
## Cumulative Proportion  0.941 0.98083 0.99448 0.99756 0.99864 0.99948
```

Comment: Why do you have so many PC's? PCA is a way to *reduce* dimensionality.

Comment: What PCA functions are you using? Please include your code and a reproducible data sample so the community can better help you.

Comment: Please see edited question. I must be doing something wrong when running PCA :(

Comment: The function `prcomp`, has a `tol=` argument to limit the number of PCs. Try `tol=.1`. For more details look at the manual page `?prcomp`. If you want all thePCs available, keep the results without setting the tolerance, and then run the function again reducing the PCs for printing.

Comment: thanks. i also just started using `rank=` to reduce the number of components

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all.
i was omitting the threshold on how many PC's i want for my new model. either `rank` or `tol` can work for my case